# HTTP CODE = 409 errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git-push, unfuddle

We are experiencing HTTP CODE = 409 error when we are trying to push our code to the repository. I tried with different IP address and it still doesn't work.

I wonder if there's something wrong with remote side.

Here is the message we got when pushing:

```
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 409
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: recursion detected in die handler
Everything up-to-date
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Content-Type, like that one application/json. Attached link have a example:
http://blog.app4domain.com/2016/12/got-409-http-return-code-in-jboss.html

Conflicts are most likely to occur in response to a PUT request. For example, if versioning were being used and the entity being PUT included changes to a resource which conflict with those made by an earlier (third-party) request, the server might use the 409 response to indicate that it can't complete the request. In this case, the response entity would likely contain a list of the differences between the two versions in a format defined by the response Content-Type.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html